# Django rest auth with Allauth

Tags: django-rest-framework, access-token, django-allauth, google-signin, django-rest-auth

I have implemented django rest auth with Allauth and its working fine if I login through google `access_token` but there is a case when some client device need to login by google `id_token`.
I am getting error if I use `id_token` instead of `access_token`

```
{
  "non_field_errors": [
    "Incorrect value"
  ]
}
```

please help me out

Comment: Can you give more context please? Request payload? url? etc.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: how are you getting access_token from google?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Update your files like

`../allauth/socialaccount/providers/google/provider.py`:

```
class GoogleProvider(OAuth2Provider):
    ....

    def extract_uid(self, data):
        try:
            return str(data['id'])
        except KeyError:
            return str(data['user_id'])
```

`../allauth/socialaccount/providers/google/views.py`:

```
class GoogleOAuth2Adapter(OAuth2Adapter):
    provider_id = GoogleProvider.id
    access_token_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    authorize_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
    profile_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo'
    token_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo'

    def complete_login(self, request, app, token, **kwargs):
        if 'rest-auth/google' in request.path:
            print('rest-auth api')
            # /api/rest-auth/google
            # but not for website login with google
            resp = requests.get(self.token_url,
                            params={'id_token': token.token,
                                    'alt': 'json'})
        else:
            print('else else rest-auth api')
            resp = requests.get(self.profile_url,
                            params={'access_token': token.token,
                                    'alt': 'json'})
        resp.raise_for_status()
        extra_data = resp.json()
        login = self.get_provider() \
            .sociallogin_from_response(request,
                                   extra_data)
        return login


oauth2_login = OAuth2LoginView.adapter_view(GoogleOAuth2Adapter)
oauth2_callback = OAuth2CallbackView.adapter_view(GoogleOAuth2Adapter)
```

For using id_token you will get only these fileds (access_type, audience, email, email_verified, expires_in, issued_at, issued_to, issuer, nonce, scope, user_id, verified_email). So if your user table required **phone** and **name** you can set the to empty `name=''` etc. For this you can use the following code.

Set user model required fields to empty for covering **id_token** case

It depends upon your user model, in my case we need both phone and name so I have set them empty. If you don't do this you will get failed constraints errors.

`../allauth/socialaccount/providers/base.py`

```
class Provider(object):
    def sociallogin_from_response(self, request, response):
        ....
        common_fields = self.extract_common_fields(response)
        common_fields['name'] = common_fields.get('name', '')
        common_fields['phone'] = common_fields.get('phone', '')
        common_fields['username'] = uid
        ....
```

I have set the username to user id obtained from social platform api. Later I am forcing user to update its details (username, name, phone etc).

Comment: Hey.. I'm newbie to django. Just getting the hang of things. Could you please let me know where to make these changes ? Should write a custom provider based on allauth is it ?

Comment: you need to customize django-allauth library itself.